# Can someone help me understand the code that obfuscated my file so that I can reverse it?

Tags: batch-file

Recently I obfuscated my own code for a password protection and used

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" exit /b
if /i "%~x1" neq ".bat" if /i "%~x1" neq ".cmd" exit /b
for /f %%i in ("certutil.exe") do if not exist "%%~$path:i" (
  echo CertUtil.exe not found.
  pause
  exit /b
)
>"temp.~b64" echo(//4mY2xzDQo=
certutil.exe -f -decode "temp.~b64" "%~n1o%~x1"
del "temp.~b64"
copy "%~n1o%~x1" /b + "%~1" /b
```

and Im not sure how I should reverse it so that I can change my password.

Comment: I would like to add that it makes my code into something in mandarin

Comment: Where did you get this script ? Don't forget to add its reference or link !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this answer [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=53147#p53147) or [here too](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=53133#p53133)

---

You can drag and drop your obfuscated file over this batch file in order to read an comes back your original code !

```bat
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" exit /b
if /i "%~x1" neq ".bat" if /i "%~x1" neq ".cmd" exit /b
if exist "%~n1___%~x1" del "%~n1___%~x1"
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%L in ('CMD /U /C Type "%~1"') do (
   echo %%L
   echo %%L >>"%~n1___%~x1"
)
pause>nul
```

---

OR this :

```bat
@echo off &setlocal
if "%~1"=="" exit /b
if /i "%~x1" neq ".bat" if /i "%~x1" neq ".cmd" exit /b
<"%~1" ((for /l %%N in (1 1 8) do pause)>nul&findstr "^">"%~n1___%~x1")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I made a batch tool for my friend and now I can change the password for him! You are honestly such a good person.